# Identify this high wing aircraft with engine side-pods

Tags: aircraft-identification

Was watching [this video from 1967](https://youtu.be/D7CuoP6iOnc?t=1477) and saw an interesting high-wing plane that looks to be about the size of a Cessna 206, but with what looks like a really unique dual engine side-pod configuration. I was unable to figure out what the make/model is if anyone is familiar.

[image: podplane]

Comment: It looks like a Stinson Model U Airliner, but seems too small.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a Dornier Do 28 A1. The aircraft first flew in 1959, and was followed by the similar but larger Do28 C in 1966. You'll find more on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Do_28)

[image]

Source: [Wikipedia Commons](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dornier_Do_28_A1_from_left_Dornier_Museum_2009-09-27.jpg#mw-jump-to-license)